# Best practice to implement a LRU or LFU cache eviction policy while using the browser Cache interface?

Tags: browser-cache

I'm using the [`window.caches` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) to cache some heavy data (GBs of data) on the client. It's unclear how the eviction policy works for this interface.

I read it is supposed to error if the origin quota is reached, but should fallback to LRU or LFU (depending by the browser) if the global browser limits are reached.

How should I go about implementing a consistent cache eviction policy while using this interface? Are there any APIs provided by this interface that could help me with the implementation?